# Cannot connect firebase database. says export not found

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Tried linking firabase to my react front-end but got this error message;

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/Feed.js 21:4-17
>
> export 'default' (imported as 'db') was not found in '../firebase' (module has no exports)

I'm using V9 above of firabase and tried all the solutions on here so adding compat: `import 'firebase'compat'auth';`

This is my import section from feed.js

```
import "./firebase"
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import db from "./firebase";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```

and this is inside my actual firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

---- copied firebase inbetween ----

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The error is saying that it can't import your firebase instance of whatever it is you're trying to import from the `'../firebase'` file. Can you include the code for that file as well?

Comment: I added more comments inside my original post. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You'd need something like `export const db = app.database()` (or however it works with compat)

Comment: Thanks it worked! Had to add export and define it in firebase.js!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put "@" before "firebase/xxx"..
For example,
(Before)
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
(After)
import { initializeApp } from '@firebase/app';